# Agora Polling/ Voting Feature

Tags: interactive, voting, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I would like to implement a polling/ voting feature in Agora Live Streaming. Are there any resources that I can refer to? I have tried searching but there isn't anything related.

Comment: Were you able to create one?

Comment: Please have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74223998/agorartcexception-agorartcerror-ws-abort-type-ping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Agora's RTM SDK to implement this feature yourself. On the host side, you can send a channel message to start a poll. On receiving the message on the audience's side, appropriate UI must be constructed.

And now, the audience/attendees can respond to the poll by sending out another channel message to register their vote.

RTM SDK link: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/messaging_web?platform=Web